# Importing Solr Cores from one old Solr to another

Tags: solr

I have old version of Solr on one server. I have 4 Cores in it. I have installed new fresh Solr on new server. I have physically moved the old core directories as well, to new server Cores directory, but I cannot find a way to import them to new Solr instance.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

If you have an already existing Solr index and you want to try new settings, it is best to work and test on a copy Solr’s index first.
Here are the simple steps to make a copy of your Solr’s index:
Suppose we have already an index named cast and the copy will be named LuckBox.

- Make new directory under solr (e.g. LuckBox)
- Copy the entire directories conf and lib from cast to LuckBox.
- Make new directory called data under the new directory LuckBox.
- Add to solr.xml your new index name `<core instanceDir=”LuckBox” name=”LuckBox” />`
- Restart Jetty (e.g. sudo /etc/init.d/jetty restart)
- Go to `http://localhost:8983/solr/LuckBox/admin/dataimport.jsp?handler=/dataimport`

  ```
  1 : click on Reload-config
  2 : click on Full-import
  3 : continue to next step only after the status became “idle” (by clicking on Status).
  ```

  - Test your new index by: http://localhost:8983/solr/LuckBox/select/?q=*:*&start=0&rows=10&indent=on

Comment: Should I set the first core offline or in a special modus while I copy it?